# How to flatten a column of nested json objects in an already flattened dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, json-normalize

I have a json file with nested objects which is flattened in a pandas dataframe. There is a single column with nested json objects that I find hard the flatten.

I have tried many approaches, this is the approach that got me the furthest.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

*Unfortunately I was unable to find a jsfiddle like alternative for python to provide a working example.*

I understand that with the meta parameter of json_normalize I can add columns to my dataframe. But that approach does not work on the unflat column because I only got json_normalize to work well in my setup by setting record_path to 'markets' which is the main json object in my file. So in this setup I am unable to record_path to 'marketStats' and add any relevant columns via the meta parameter.

**Goal**

The goal is to transform one or all json objects in the marketStats object in to columns of the dataframe.

**Code**

```
with open('Data/20012022.json') as file:
data = json.loads(file.read())

# Flatten data
df0 = pd.json_normalize(
      data, 
      record_path =['markets']
)

df0.head(3)
```

**Screenshot**

This is a screenshot of what the table currently looks like, the marketStats column contains nested json.

[image]

**Data**

This a snippet from the json file. `

```
{
  "markets": [
    {
      "id": 335,
      "baseCurrency": "eth",
      "quoteCurrency": "btc",
      "exchangeName": "Binance",
      "exchangeCode": "BINA",
      "longName": "BTC-ETH",
      "marketName": "btc-eth",
      "symbol": "ETHBTC",
      "volume": "40624.5823",
      "quoteVolume": "3026.13646935",
      "btcVolume": "3026.13646935",
      "usdVolume": "127009429.050524367",
      "currentPrice": 0.074681,
      "latestBase": {
        "id": 161774475,
        "time": 1639576800,
        "date": "2021-12-15T14:00:00.000+00:00",
        "price": "0.077653",
        "lowestPrice": "0.0729",
        "bounce": "6.283",
        "currentDrop": "-3.8272829124438206",
        "crackedAt": "2022-01-07T03:00:00.000Z",
        "respectedAt": "2022-01-15T15:00:00.000Z",
        "isLowest": false
      },
      "marketStats": [
        {
          "algorithm": "original",
          "ratio": "50.0",
          "medianDrop": "-4.08",
          "medianBounce": "5.51",
          "hoursToRespected": 106,
          "crackedCount": 2,
          "respectedCount": 1
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "day_trade",
          "ratio": "100.0",
          "medianDrop": "-6.12",
          "medianBounce": "6.28",
          "hoursToRespected": 204,
          "crackedCount": 1,
          "respectedCount": 1
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "conservative",
          "ratio": "100.0",
          "medianDrop": "-6.12",
          "medianBounce": "8.38",
          "hoursToRespected": 204,
          "crackedCount": 1,
          "respectedCount": 1
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "position",
          "ratio": "50.0",
          "medianDrop": "-6.12",
          "medianBounce": "6.19",
          "hoursToRespected": 204,
          "crackedCount": 2,
          "respectedCount": 1
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "hodloo",
          "ratio": "50.0",
          "medianDrop": "-3.29",
          "medianBounce": "0.0",
          "hoursToRespected": 225,
          "crackedCount": 4,
          "respectedCount": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 337,
      "baseCurrency": "ltc",
      "quoteCurrency": "btc",
      "exchangeName": "Binance",
      "exchangeCode": "BINA",
      "longName": "BTC-LTC",
      "marketName": "btc-ltc",
      "symbol": "LTCBTC",
      "volume": "68309.637",
      "quoteVolume": "223.79294524",
      "btcVolume": "223.79294524",
      "usdVolume": "9392773.4219378968",
      "currentPrice": 0.003275,
      "latestBase": {
        "id": 163982984,
        "time": 1642374000,
        "date": "2022-01-16T23:00:00.000+00:00",
        "price": "0.003346",
        "lowestPrice": "0.00322",
        "bounce": "3.839",
        "currentDrop": "-2.1219366407650926",
        "crackedAt": "2022-01-18T23:00:00.000Z",
        "respectedAt": null,
        "isLowest": false
      },
      "marketStats": [
        {
          "algorithm": "original",
          "ratio": "57.14",
          "medianDrop": "-3.28",
          "medianBounce": "3.84",
          "hoursToRespected": 186,
          "crackedCount": 7,
          "respectedCount": 4
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "day_trade",
          "ratio": "0.0",
          "medianDrop": "0.0",
          "medianBounce": "5.68",
          "hoursToRespected": 0,
          "crackedCount": 1,
          "respectedCount": 0
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "conservative",
          "ratio": "0.0",
          "medianDrop": "0.0",
          "medianBounce": "5.68",
          "hoursToRespected": 0,
          "crackedCount": 1,
          "respectedCount": 0
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "position",
          "ratio": "0.0",
          "medianDrop": "0.0",
          "medianBounce": "8.16",
          "hoursToRespected": 0,
          "crackedCount": 1,
          "respectedCount": 0
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "hodloo",
          "ratio": "75.0",
          "medianDrop": "-3.7",
          "medianBounce": "0.0",
          "hoursToRespected": 35,
          "crackedCount": 4,
          "respectedCount": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 339,
      "baseCurrency": "bnb",
      "quoteCurrency": "btc",
      "exchangeName": "Binance",
      "exchangeCode": "BINA",
      "longName": "BTC-BNB",
      "marketName": "btc-bnb",
      "symbol": "BNBBTC",
      "volume": "154576.177",
      "quoteVolume": "1724.66664804",
      "btcVolume": "1724.66664804",
      "usdVolume": "72385673.4448901928",
      "currentPrice": 0.01099,
      "latestBase": {
        "id": 163753765,
        "time": 1642068000,
        "date": "2022-01-13T10:00:00.000+00:00",
        "price": "0.01093",
        "lowestPrice": "0.01093",
        "bounce": "3.102",
        "currentDrop": "0.5489478499542543",
        "crackedAt": null,
        "respectedAt": null,
        "isLowest": false
      },
      "marketStats": [
        {
          "algorithm": "original",
          "ratio": "100.0",
          "medianDrop": "-7.18",
          "medianBounce": "4.34",
          "hoursToRespected": 62,
          "crackedCount": 2,
          "respectedCount": 2
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "day_trade",
          "ratio": "100.0",
          "medianDrop": "-6.19",
          "medianBounce": "4.3",
          "hoursToRespected": 63,
          "crackedCount": 1,
          "respectedCount": 1
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "conservative",
          "ratio": "66.67",
          "medianDrop": "-3.15",
          "medianBounce": "4.05",
          "hoursToRespected": 62,
          "crackedCount": 3,
          "respectedCount": 2
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "position",
          "ratio": "100.0",
          "medianDrop": "-3.15",
          "medianBounce": "4.46",
          "hoursToRespected": 60,
          "crackedCount": 2,
          "respectedCount": 2
        },
        {
          "algorithm": "hodloo",
          "ratio": "100.0",
          "medianDrop": "-7.46",
          "medianBounce": "0.0",
          "hoursToRespected": 62,
          "crackedCount": 5,
          "respectedCount": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply some post-processing to `df0` to achieve what you want. Here you can apply `explode` followed by `apply(pf.Series)` applied to `'marketStats'` column:

```
df1 = df0.explode('marketStats')['marketStats'].apply(pd.Series)
```

`df1` looks like this:

```
    algorithm       ratio    medianDrop    medianBounce    hoursToRespected    crackedCount    respectedCount
--  ------------  -------  ------------  --------------  ------------------  --------------  ----------------
 0  original        50            -4.08            5.51                 106               2                 1
 0  day_trade      100            -6.12            6.28                 204               1                 1
 0  conservative   100            -6.12            8.38                 204               1                 1
 0  position        50            -6.12            6.19                 204               2                 1
 0  hodloo          50            -3.29            0                    225               4                 2
 1  original        57.14         -3.28            3.84                 186               7                 4
 1  day_trade        0             0               5.68                   0               1                 0
 1  conservative     0             0               5.68                   0               1                 0
 1  position         0             0               8.16                   0               1                 0
 1  hodloo          75            -3.7             0                     35               4                 3
 2  original       100            -7.18            4.34                  62               2                 2
 2  day_trade      100            -6.19            4.3                   63               1                 1
 2  conservative    66.67         -3.15            4.05                  62               3                 2
 2  position       100            -3.15            4.46                  60               2                 2
 2  hodloo         100            -7.46            0                     62               5                 5
```

if you want it combined with all the other columns you can use `join`:

```
df0.join(df1)
```

I am not going to post the output of this command as it is rather large

Comment: I found your solution the most straightforward and does the job. Thank you.